# Restassured Parse Body response with boundary

Tags: java, download, get, rest-assured, boundary

I use RestAssured, and I'm trying to download files with de GET call.

My issue is that the request body is organised with a boundary.

So the file I get contain too many informations and is not usable. 
Here is an exemple of content of a simple text file downloaded :

> --a8f82a89-d9c2-4fcb-a612-06e286bfcf66
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="metadata"; filename="metadata"
>   Content-Type: application/json
>   {"name":"Fichier_de_calcul.txt","id":{"metadata":{"deleted":false,"ephemeral":false,"synthesised":true,"systemOwned":true,"readOnly":false,"synchronisable":true,"createdOn":"2018-11-09T15:36:39Z","enabled":true,"lastModifiedOn":"2018-11-09T15:36:40.444Z"},"value":{"@type":"CoreKit.UUIDKey","value":"4de39a67-0075-4232-a236-09ab8d10aed9"}}}
>   --a8f82a89-d9c2-4fcb-a612-06e286bfcf66
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="@type"; filename="@type"
>   Content-Type: text/plain
>   CoreKit.FileMetadataAndFile
>   --a8f82a89-d9c2-4fcb-a612-06e286bfcf66
>   Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="file"
>   Content-Type: application/octet-stream
>   2
>   4
>   6
>   8
>   10
>   --a8f82a89-d9c2-4fcb-a612-06e286bfcf66--

And here is the code I used to get this file :

```
    Response resp = RestAssured.given().headers(headers).get(url);
    byte[] fileContent = resp.body().asByteArray();
    File fileToSave = new File(classPath);
    try {
        Files.write(fileContent, fileToSave);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Does someone know how I can do to :

Parse the body (I'd like to get the "filename" parameter)
Create the downloaded file based on the "application/octet-stream" part.

Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try below appraoch:
you can set all header which you have and get request with your url.

```
    Response response=RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/json").get("yourURL").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();
String finaleNAme=response.jsonPath().get("jsonValuewhichyouwanttoget");
```

Comment: I'm trying right now, but it dosen't work. Because of my headers. I have to put specific kay in my headers, otherwise the API send me an error.

Comment: instead of setting content-type application/json use application/octet-stream and check all your header and set in this request.

Comment: Actually, if I do this code : Response response=RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/json").get("yourURL").then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response();

Comment: Yes, then what happened?

Comment: Actually, if I do this code : Response response=RestAssured.given().header("Content-Type", "application/json").get(url).then().contentType(ContentType.JSON).extract().response(); I got an error message specifying that I didn't send the API-KEY in the headers.     After If I set my headers, I got error, because the response Content-type is "multipart/form-data", so When I extract data specifying "multipart/form-data", the response I get Is the same as what I get when I use de getBody() method

Comment: You mean to say this solution is not helping you right?

Comment: This solution seems right (I was able to extract a specific part of the error message), but not in my context, because I can't set a unique header. anyhow thank you !